# Optimize strategy results in R

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have a strategy ***S*** which is the results of ***Ws*** (the weight matrix) %*% ***rets*** (the returns of the assets the strategy is trading).
To be clear:

**PNL = cumsum(rets %*% Ws)**

The PNL of the strategy need to satisfy certain requirements:
- zero correlation with the market
- min weight for each security xL
- max weight for each security xH
- some more

Assuming I have an optimizer able to satisfy the constraints above, what is the input I should put into the optimizer ? 
If I put simple returns, ***rets***, I'm not considering my strategy.
I tried to use **rets * Ws**, i.e. the securities returns multiplied by the respective weights of the strategy, but the **PNL** after the optimizer looks much worse than before optimizer. Is it the right way to do it ? 
Any advice would be very appreciated.

Second question: so far I used as optimizer PortfolioAnalytics with "Deoptim" algorithm (super slow) and parma (much better, but still a bit slow and doesn't give documentation for some constraints I need). I used fPortfolio years ago with no great satisfaction. Any suggestion in R or I should move on to commercial optimizers ?

Thanks everyone!